# Project set up not woring

Tags: angular

i am working on the Angular2 project. This project is working in the other system on which i was working but somehow i have to switch my project in other system. When i set up same project with same configuration like npm, cli in the other system and run the it does not work and give error. I have uninstall cli, clear cache and reinstall cli but not work. please advise.Please refer attached error image.
[image]

Please refer the error: ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/@agm/core/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/Saumil/Lakonia/lcgoopcomanuel1lp/src/app/app.module.ts

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "well-application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/videojs": "^5.16.2",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.35",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fractional": "^1.0.0",
    "javascript-to-typescript": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-accordion": "0.0.15",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^5.3.1",
    "ng2-ion-range-slider": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and paste in the contents of package.json file?

Comment: please copy here the full error log in your posted image

Comment: ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/@agm/core/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: add the above error log to the question description, comments may not be seen by many users.

Comment: you're using cli version 6. with a project of version 1.3.2. are you sure it's supposed to work, as far as i remember at version 1.3.2 we used `angular-cli.json` and since 6.0 we use `angular.json` can you try downgrade your CLI and see ?

Comment: can you post the package.json here?

Comment: @Stavm same project and same configuration is working in other system

Comment: @saumil_jariwala please post your `package.json` then.

Comment: @Stavm please open this url https://notepad.pw/3kepx1xy

Comment: @saumil_jariwala I've added it into the question instead.

Comment: did you see [this suggestion](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1456#issuecomment-405462441) on your google search ?

Comment: Please see my edited url for package.json

Comment: From the package.json i have removed "^" from the  "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1", and it works because when i use "^1.0.0-beta.1", then it takes higher version "1.0.0-beta.3" and it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myslef by removing "^" from the "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1", and it works because when i use "^1.0.0-beta.1", then it takes higher version "1.0.0-beta.3" and it was not working –

Answer (score 0):

Your posted image is not clear. But it seems that the error is related to mismatch in node module version (specially agm package).

I think by deleting **node_modules** directory in your project, and then running `npm install` it will install the proper version of packages. Try it.

Comment: did  you tried to delete package-lock.json and try again?

Comment: Yes i deleted package-lock.json, deleted node modules and use command npm install but still getting error